# Laravel - How to create a query with where clause using subquery?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to generate this query using Laravel:

```
select mygames.id, mygames.name, mygames.slug, mygames.cover from mygames 
left join mygame_mygenre on mygames.id = mygame_mygenre.mygame_id 
left join mygame_myplatform on mygames.id = mygame_myplatform.mygame_id 
where mygame_mygenre.mygenre_id in (8, 9, 31, 32, 33) 
and mygame_myplatform.myplatform_id in (3, 6, 14, 34, 37, 39, 46, 48, 72, 130) 
and mygames.id <> 1990
and mygames.summary is not null 
and (select count(mygame_id) from mygame_myplatform where mygame_id = mygames.id) > 1 
group by mygames.id, mygames.name, mygames.slug, cover 
order by RAND() 
limit 6
```

My current code is:

```
$games = DB::table('mygames')
            ->leftjoin('mygame_mygenre', 'mygames.id', '=', 'mygame_mygenre.mygame_id')
            ->leftjoin('mygame_myplatform', 'mygames.id', '=', 'mygame_myplatform.mygame_id')
            ->select('mygames.id', 'mygames.name', 'mygames.slug', 'cover')
            ->when($genres_id, function ($query, $genres_id) {
                return $query->whereIn('mygame_mygenre.mygenre_id', $genres_id);
            })
            ->when($platforms_id, function ($query, $platforms_id) {
                return $query->whereIn('mygame_myplatform.myplatform_id', $platforms_id);
            })
            ->where('mygames.id', '<>', $this->id)
            ->whereNotNull('mygames.summary')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('count(mygame_id)')
                ->from('mygame_myplatform')
                ->where('mygame_id', 'mygames.id');
            }, '>', 1)
            ->groupBy('mygames.id', 'mygames.name', 'mygames.slug', 'cover')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->take(6)
            ->get();
```

This code is not working because inside the closure function I was unable to pass the name of the mygames table with the id field. Laravel is interpreting as a text parameter and not as a table.field

```
->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->selectRaw('count(mygame_id)')
                    ->from('mygame_myplatform')
                    ->where('mygame_id', 'mygames.id'); <<<<<<<<<<<<<
                }, '>', 1)
```

I tried to use `'use ()'` but it didn't work either.

Could you help me?

Comment: Instead of using DB helper class, trying using Eloquent Relations and and functions like whereHas(), with(). Once you define valid relations, with() and whereHas() can make your life simple and code easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you must use the `whereColumn` method to achieve this.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses
Another solution is to use the `whereRaw` method.
See :

```php
DB::table('mygames')
            ->select(['mygames.id', 'mygames.name', 'mygames.slug', 'mygames.cover'])
            ->leftJoin('mygames_mygenre', 'mygames.id', '=', 'mygame_mygenre.mygame_id')
            ->leftJoin('mygame_myplatform', 'mygames.id', '=', 'mygame_myplatform.mygame_id')
            ->whereIn('mygame_mygenre.mygenre_id', [8, 9, 31, 32, 33])
            ->whereIn('mygame_myplatform.myplatform_id', [3, 6, 14, 34, 37, 39, 46, 48, 72, 130])
            ->where('mygames.id', '<>', 1990)
            ->whereNotNull('mygames.summary')
            ->where(1, '<', function ($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('COUNT(mygame_id)')
                    ->from('mygame_myplatform')
                    ->whereColumn('mygame_id', 'mygames.id');
            })
            ->groupBy('mygames.id', 'mygames.name', 'mygames.slug', 'cover')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->take(6)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I assume you're trying to compare 2 columns, right?

```php
->where('mygame_id', 'mygames.id');
```

In that case, use the `whereColumn/orWhereColumn` method.

```php
->whereColumn('mygame_id', 'mygames.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

looks similar to @jascar_destin answer, but on the group by, you ll have to specify which table the cover is been picked from except if cover does not exists on other tables rather than mygames.

```
DB::table('mygames AS mg')
        ->leftJoin('mygame_mygenre AS mgmg', 'mgmg.mygame_id', '=', 'mg.id')
        ->leftJoin('mygame_myplatform AS mgmp', 'mgmp.mygame_id', '=', 'mg.id')
        ->select(['mg.id', 'mg.name', 'mg.slug', 'mg.cover'])
        ->whereIn('mgmg.my_genre_id', [8, 9, 31, 32, 33])
        ->whereIn('mgmp.my_platform_id'. [3, 6, 14, 34, 37, 39, 46, 48, 72, 130])
        ->where('mg.id', '<>', 1990)
        ->whereNotNull('mg.summary')
        ->where(1, '<', function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('COUNT(mygame_id)')
                ->from('mygame_myplatform')
                ->whereColumn('mygame_id', 'mg.id');
        })
        ->groupBy('mg.id', 'mg.name', 'mg.slug', 'mg.cover')
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->take(6)
        ->get();
```